# Need a date instead of datetime in SQL Server 2005 with dateadd

Tags: sql-server-2005, dateadd

I've got a query that get's a date of a field in a program. This date has to be modified with 10 years.

The query I made is

```
SELECT DATEADD(yy, +10, '"+thisfield.value+"')
```

where `'"+thisfield.value+"'` is coming from the program and is filled in like `01-08-2012`.

The result of the query is `2022-07-31 00:00:00.000`. The problem I have is that I just need `2022-08-01` but in the format of `01-08-2022` so that I can automatically fill an other field with this result.

In SQL Server 2005 the date function doesn't work only the datetime function and I just don't need that.

I hope this is clear (first time i post something). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Really you shouldn't build your SQL like this in the first place, for performance and SQL Injection vulnerabilities. The proper way it to using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either truncate the result, or cast it to DATE

```
CAST(DATEADD(yy, +10, '"+thisfield.value+"') AS DATE)" 

CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(yy, +10, '"+thisfield.value+"'), 101)"
```

CONVERT using style 101 is in the format mm/dd/yyyy, which happens to be the format you want.  Keep in mind that you can format the result however you want in your application for display purposes which is better than returning strings from SQL Server.

Also note that you should look into parameterized queries and/or stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction.The first answer doesn't work. I get the error: Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: but the second answer is the solution.